# can't delete http-only cookie in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cookies

I have a nodejs server with a login controller, where I create a cookie with a token:

```
res.cookie('token', token, { domain: '.mydomain.com', httpOnly: true, secure: true });
```

As you can see, it's a http-only cookie over https. This cookie is set, because I can use it in subsequent queries. The problem is, I can't delete this cookie. I have a logout controller with this code:

```
res.clearCookie('token');
```

The cookie is not deleted, because when I refresh my page, I'm still logged in.

When I leave out th domain-property, it works! Am I using my domain-property the wrong way? I need it for the www and the non-www version.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.clearCookie) clearCookie accepts options :

So you can simply pass the same options as your cookie creation and do :

```
res.clearCookie('token', { domain: '.mydomain.com', httpOnly: true, secure: true })
```